# virtuemart sort products by position

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

how can you sort products by position (using the arrows to sort) in virtuemart 1.1.9?
I can sort the categories by position, so I don't get why you can't with the products, I can sort them by product name, price, newest products and article number only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only be able to sort by individual category to change product position in virtue mart product list.To do this filter the list by category, then you will be able to sort product by position (using the arrows to sort).

Comment: great thank! last time I'm working with virtuemart it really sucks :)